# Stream changes from Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL using Amazon Kinesis Data Streams and AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-kinesis, rds

I am trying to follow this documentation- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/stream-changes-from-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-using-amazon-kinesis-data-streams-and-aws-lambda/
in order to stream changes in the Postgres database (running in AWS rds) to AWS-Kinesis. When I run the given code in ec2 (or on my local system), it works and it prints any crud operation in the terminal. However, option 2 using lambda does not work. Nowhere has it been mentioned that how the lambda will be triggered. Also, a lambda is supposed to run for a max of 15 min. I am highly confused and would really like some help on this.

Comment: Hi Abhisek, Did you find any solution for the above? I am able to make slot and create a streaming connection but stream is not returning any changes. where as if I point to my  local poastgres db it runs perfectly. I am confused what is stopping on rds.

Comment: Same issue @VishalS. Noone replied here.

Comment: @VishalS I would recommend you to use AWS DMS for whatever you are trying to do. I did the same. It is much easier to implement.